# How to update key/value of a nested state object (React JS)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to update a key/value pair of a nested object in the state while the user types in the form. My state looks like this :

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  details: {
    detail1: {
      title: "",
      description: "",
      image1: null,
      image2: null,
    },
    detail2: {
      title: "",
      description: "",
      image1: null,
      image2: null,
    },
   detail3: {
      title: "",
      description: "",
      image1: null,
      image2: null,
    },
  },
};

}
```

This is my render method :

```
<form>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={this.state.creatives.creative1.title}
        onChange={(e) => {
          this.setState((prevState) => ({
            creatives: {
              ...prevState.creatives,
              creative1: {
                ...prevState.creatives.creative1,
                title: e.target.value,
              },
            },
          }));
          console.log(this.state.details.detail1.title);
        }}
      ></input>
    </form>
```

I have tried to update the key/value as above in the onChange method, but the console says that I cannot call .target on null. For some reason, The event.target returns null, I am not sure why. If anyone has a better solution to add the value typed to update the state, please do help.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(e, e?.target)`

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz Yes, I tried. It works and it can console log but when i do that inside the setState methods it throws me the same error of cannot read value of null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event passed to onChange is a Synthetic Event. You can't use such an event in an asynchronous way as React will reuse the event. `setState` calls the updater function in an asynchronous way. If you store the event value in a constant and access that in `setState`, it should work.

https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

```
onChange={(e) => {
   const value = e.target.value
   this.setState((prevState) => ({
       creatives: {
          ...prevState.creatives,
          creative1: {
            ...prevState.creatives.creative1,
            title: value,
          },
        },
      }));
      console.log(this.state.details.detail1.title);
    }}
```

Comment: Thank you ! That fixed the problem, but when I console log the state, Its lagging by one last character ? What could be the reason ? I have placed my console log inside the onChange method so everytime we type it logs.

Comment: I don't see the cause for that, maybe try using `e.currentTarget.value` instead?